# Is there a way to schedule a lazy timer relative to another timer?

Tags: systemd, systemd-timer

(`x-mas.service`)

```
[Unit]
Description=Celebrate X-Mas

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/x-mas-day

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

(`x-mas.timer`)

```
[Unit]
Description=Add "X-Mas" to the calendar

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-12-25 00:00:00
Unit=x-mas.service

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

(`buy-presents.service`)

```
[Unit]
Description=Get your wallet out
Requires=x-mas.service
Before=x-mas.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=open-amazon-dot-com.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

(`buy-presents.timer`)

```
[Unit]
Description=Buy presents
Before=x-mas.timer
Requires=x-mas.timer

[Timer]
OnActiveSec=1
AccuracySec=no-pressure?
RandomizedDelaySec=true?

[Install]
#WantedBy=timers.target
RequiredBy=x-mas.timer
```

Clearly there is still plenty of time from today to *buy presents* so optimized flexibility in scheduling before the 'x-mas deadline' is desired, but it was not immediately obvious to me on first reading [systemd.timer(5)](https://man.archlinux.org/man/systemd.timer.5) how to even relate timers to other timers. Can this be done with `systemd` units only?